# Downloading images in UITableViewCell with a background URLSession is very slow and gets strange error

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I need to perform correctly this, I think common, scenario:

I have an `UITableViewController` whose table's cells should download an image and show it. Number of cells depends on an user input, and I first get the URLs of the images I need to download, one per cell. In this `UITableViewController` I have this method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard results.count > 0 else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let result = results[indexPath.row]
    myCell.model = result
    myCell.imageProvider = imageProvider
    return myCell
}
```

Where `CustomCell` is like this:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

// Several IBOutlets

static let cellIdentifier = "myCell"

var imageProvider: ImageProvider?

var model: MyModel? {
    willSet {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: true)
    }
    didSet {
        guard let modelUrlStr = model?.imageUrlStr, let imageUrl = URL(string: modelUrlStr) else {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: false)
            return
        }
        
        imageProvider?.getImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: {[weak self] (image, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard error == nil else {
                    self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self?.configureImage(showImage: false,  showActivity: false)
                    return
                }
                
                self?.imageView.image = image
                self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self?.configureImage(showCoverImage: true, showActivity: false)
            }
        })
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    configureImage(showCoverImage: false, showActivity: false)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    model = nil
}

private func configureImage(showImage: Bool, showActivity: Bool) {
    // Update image view
} 
}
```

And `ImageProvider` is this:

```
class ImageProvider {
var imageTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

func getImage(imageUrl: URL, completion: @escaping DownloadResult) {
    imageTask?.cancel()
    
    imageTask = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getImageInBackground(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: { (image, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
        } else if let image = image {
            completion(image, nil)
        } else {
            completion(nil, nil)
        }
    })
}
}
```

What I need to do is:

- The user asks for a search typing a text, then I perform the search given that text parameter and get a number of results (that is, the number of cells to show in the table, and also the URLs for the images in the cells, one per cell)
- The user can change the text to search or delete it at any moment, which means that I should refresh the table after every change in that text (cancel previous search if it was in progress -> new search of results -> new images URLs -> new images download).
- I need the images keep downloading if the app goes to background state, to be able to show them when the app goes again to foreground.

Then, finally, this is `NetworkManager`:

```
class NetworkManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
fileprivate var defaultSession: URLSession
fileprivate var backgroundSession: URLSession?
fileprivate var completionHandlers = [URL : ImageResult]()

override init() { 
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    super.init()
    
    let backgroundConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.mysearch")
    backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}

func getImageInBackground(imageUrl url: URL, completion: ImageResult?) -> URLSessionDownloadTask? {
    guard let backgroundSession = self.backgroundSession else {
        return nil
    }
    
    completionHandlers[url] = completion
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)
    task.resume()
    
    return task
}
}

extension NetworkManager: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error, let url = task.originalRequest?.url, let completion = completionHandlers[url] {
        completionHandlers[url] = nil
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: location), let image = UIImage(data: data), let request = downloadTask.originalRequest, let response = downloadTask.response {
        let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data)
       self.defaultSession.configuration.urlCache?.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
        if let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url, let completion = completionHandlers[url] {
            completionHandlers[url] = nil
            completion(image, nil)
        }
    } else {
        if let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url, let completion = completionHandlers[url] {
            completionHandlers[url] = nil
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}

func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let completionHandler = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler {
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil
        completionHandler()
    }
}
}
```

When I run the app, I find that firstly most of images are not downloaded, and `urlSession(session:task:didCompleteWithError:)` is called with an error like this:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxxx.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://http://xxxxx.jpg}

and in addition sometimes an alert view with the text "cancelled" is show by the system. On the other hand, I don't understand why, when I scroll the table up and down looks like then most of the images are downloaded and shown.

I was following a similar example provided in a course in the [Ray Wenderlich](https://web.archive.org/web/20221014213807/https://www.raywenderlich.com/) website, but I don't know why my app is not working well.

What am I doing wrong? I need your help to figure it out.

**EDIT:** I updated the code in a way that I always have an `ImageProvider` in the custom cell. This is in `CustomCell` class:

```
private let imageProvider = ImageProvider()
```

But I still get the same error and "cabcelled" alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initiating image download in didSet method of the model, intern it requires the imageProvider to start downloading. You are setting model before setting imageProvider.

Try by updating code as below,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
guard results.count > 0 else {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
let result = results[indexPath.row]
myCell.imageProvider = imageProvider
myCell.model = result
return myCell
```

}

Comment: Sorry but what are you doing different there?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but system keeps showing the alert view with the text "cancelled".